# android studio ParseError at [row,col]:[9,9] Message: Attribute name "co" associated with an element type "item" must be followed by the

Tags: android

[ParseError at [row,col]:[9,9]
Message: Attribute name "co" associated with an element type "item" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
**strong text**strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPaXL.png)

Answer (score 0):

post code please, not much information

Comment: Welcome as a new contributor =)
Please provide tips/comments about improving questions as a comment to the original question instead of using the answer funtion. The answer function should only be used to answer the question.